# Fullcalendar dynamic height depending on width

Tags: fullcalendar

Is it possible to make the value of the 'height' tag the same as the 'width' of the table? The width changes on different screens so I think the height tag should be filled with a piece of jQuery code? I would lik to do this in order to make an exact square (and also all the td's squares).

Thanks.

Jan

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the [Aspect Ratio](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/aspectRatio/).
From doc:

> The following example will initialize a calendar who's width is twice
>   its height:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    aspectRatio: 2
});
```

So, in your case:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    aspectRatio: 1
});
```

aspectRatio is one of those properties that already have setters, so you can define it after initializing the calendar:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('option', 'aspectRatio', 1);
```